# How to estimate parallel potential of a sequential algorithm?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

Given a sequential algorithm, Is there any tools to help me find what I could parallelize and what I could not (Data-flow analysis could be starting point maybe)?

My main goal is to target OpenCL at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any compiler with the ability to auto-parallelise code could help you.  Whether you can persuade the compiler to emit anything more useful than the parallelised assembler is another matter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I doubt I can rely on automatic parallelisation though. I will have to manually "design" the new algorithm. However, a (visual) tool to help me identify good candidates would be really helpful because the algorithm and associated data structures are quite complex. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be the best we can do automatically up to date. Thanks for your help!